# Show top 5 records (Crystal reports for Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web, crystal-reports

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 and am using ASP.net/C# as the environment. I have installed Crystal reports. I am using 2 fields: business name and number of emails received

I have created report to show a graph and have created a connection and everything. Now it displays the graph (pie chart) but it shows all 20 records.

I right clicked on my report and chose Insert --> Summary --> Choose field to summarize: number of emails received. Then Calculate this summary: Nth largest is 5.

There is only Grand Total (Report Footer) and Summary location. I clicked OK. Created an new webform placed CrystalReportSource and CrystalReportViewer and created connection between them. Ran the web page, but pie chart doesnt show top 5. I am really confused. Help would be much appreciated

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you post the code related to the issue that you are having.

Comment: you can filter record before giving source to report.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your summary should not be in the Report Footer, but in the Group Footer or Header. 
You have generally two sort options and that is either by record or by group. The Top Nth sorting option is only available for the group, but if you don't have a summary within your group then the report can't sort. 
I hope this helps and if you need more help then it would be beneficial to give a little more info about your report, i.e. what groups you have, what fields you are using, etc.

Cheers,

Chris